# AngularJS - How can I reference the property name within an ng-Repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

In addition to rendering the value of the properties in an object, I'd also like to render the property name as a label.  Is there a way to do this with `ng-repeat`?  For example:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="option in data">{{propertyName}}: {{option}}</li>
</ul>
```

Which might spit out something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>Name: John</li>
    <li>Phone: (123) 456-7890</li>
    <li>Country: England</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 342, accepted):

Try this:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(key,val) in data">{{key}}: {{val}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Andy - they aren't so great, actually.  They need more simple actual code examples like you have shown here.  Thanks for your answer and please keep posting to StackOverflow; your post really helped me understand how to access the AngularJS docs.  Best regards and upvote!

Comment: so easy but didn't think of it :D tnx!

Comment: what to do if i have a function like --- myFunc(key) --- that need the key value  this gonne show me the name key in html and not the value

Answer (score 28):

The problem with documentation is that it says `(key, value)` with that space ... it took me some time to figure out that because of that it doesn't work

Comment: Thanks so much. You are right. You cannot have a space between the comma and the value. (key,value) not (key, value).

Comment: Maybe things are different in newer releases of Angular, but you can have a space between `(key, val)`. That's often how I do it.

Comment: I found (key, value) didn't work for me. Are you saying it's because of the whitespace??? Geez! But thanks.

Comment: Works for me with the space as well.

Comment: val vs value affecting the space?