# How can I list by keys and values in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AngularJS - How can I reference the property name within an ng-Repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954286/angularjs-how-can-i-reference-the-property-name-within-an-ng-repeat)

I have a JSON file like that:

```
fields: {
    alias: {
        type: "string",
    },
    name: {
        type: "string",
    }
}
```

I want something like that:

```
<dl ng-repeat="for field in fields.items">
    <dt>
        {{ field.key }}
    </dt>
    <dd>
        {{ field.value }}
    </dd>
</dl>
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: found an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954286/angularjs-how-can-i-reference-the-property-name-within-an-ng-repeat

Answer (score 14, accepted):

according to ngRepeat docs you can use "(key, value) in expression" as parameters – where key and value can be any user defined identifiers, and expression is the scope expression giving the collection to enumerate.

For example: (name, age) in {'adam':10, 'amalie':12}.

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat

Comment: Sweet! Thank you.  It's probably silly but simple answers here actually are helping me a lot with learning to read and implement the AngularJS docs.