# AngularJS - ngRepeat usage

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of items, each has its own item.value and item.name. I want to generate HTML code as follows:

```
<option value="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</option>
```

how can I do it in AngularJS? Thanks a lot.

UPDATE: I forget to mention the list I have is an object because I want to associate the Id to use it as an index, for e.g.:

```
$scope.list={
    0:{value:0,name:"name0"},
    5:{value:5,name:"name5"}
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - How can I reference the property name within an ng-Repeat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954286/angularjs-how-can-i-reference-the-property-name-within-an-ng-repeat)

Comment: Use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat` when using selects - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13803665/angularjs-value-attribute-for-select

Comment: yes I have tried those methods but didn't know why they didn't work for me, then I just realized that I have an object containing all items, not an array. Please check my update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function Ctrl($scope) {  
  $scope.list={
      0:{value:0,name:"name0"},
      5:{value:5,name:"name5"}
  }
}
```

Along with:

```
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="item in list" value="{{item.value}}">{{item.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Working: http://plnkr.co/edit/7ueudpXuGwmQt627fZGE?p=preview

Comment: the list I have is an object, sorry for not mentioning that:
`$scope.list={
    0:{value:0,name:"asdf"},
    1:{value:1,name:"bsdf"}
  }`

Comment: Works with that as well :http://plnkr.co/edit/7ueudpXuGwmQt627fZGE?p=preview since the for iterates over every key property. Doesn't matter if its a list or obj.

Comment: ahh, there is a typo in the key name and thus obj.key returns undefined, so Angular evals the expression as an empty string. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Using ng-options with your object model:

```
<select ng-options="v.value as v.name for (k,v) in list" ng-model="selected">
  <option value="">select a value</option>
</select>
<div>{{selected}}</div>
```

Your model:

```
function Ctrl($scope) {  
    $scope.list={
      0:{value:0,name:"name0"},
      5:{value:5,name:"name5"}
  }
}
```

Working Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/uNJXlCObZdhT96YDje5p?p=preview

Comment: It's better version in my honest opinion.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier I agree. I don't know how to get selected in the other version. Which is what I highlight in this version :)