# Angular js function to add counts based on match in names

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an angular app in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZKOJSGGK5hpkbMYLny0v?p=preview)

I have a text area which has some text in the format of (key,count) in them by default.

What i am trying to achieve is this(in the calc() function):

When the `button` is pressed the results of the summation should be displayed.

I was able to split the data from the textarea into different arrays but i am missing the logic to add when the names match.

**EDIT:
please notice a few updates in my plunker**

New to angular and javascript!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it.

JS:-

```
$scope.calc = function() {
  $scope.users = {};

   $scope.values.split('\n').forEach(function(itm){
     var person = itm.split(','),
         name,
         key;

      if(! itm.trim() || !person.length) return;

      name = person[0].trim()
      key = name.toLowerCase();

      $scope.users[key] = $scope.users[key] || {name:name, count:0};
      $scope.users[key].count += +person[1] || 0;
    });
}
```

HTML:-

```
<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(k,user) in users">The total for {{user.name}} is {{user.count}}</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BI5SuF?p=preview)**

Add shim for [trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) for older browsers.

Comment: hi can i get some help here?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625546/angularjs-create-a-dynamic-header-dropdowns-using-json-data

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it.  I can't speak to performance against PSL's method, but I think this reads a little easier to my not-very good at javascript eyes.

```js
function groupByName(names) {
  inputArray = names.split('\n');
  outputArray = {};

  for (i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {

      var keyValuePair = inputArray[i].split(',');
      var key = keyValuePair[0];
      var count = Number(keyValuePair[1]);

      // create element if it doesnt' exist
      if (!outputArray[key]) outputArray[key] = 0;

      // increment by value
      outputArray[key] += count;
  }

  return outputArray;
}
```

This will produce an object that looks like this:

```js
{
  "John": 6,
  "Jane": 8
}
```

You can display the [name of each property *and* it's value with ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10954998/1366033):

```html
<li ng-repeat="(key, value) in groupedNames">
  The total for {{key}} is {{value}}
</li>
```

It's not an overwhelmingly complex bit of javascript, depending on the number of name value pairs.  So you can probably even get rid of the manual calc button and just put a [`$watch`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope) on `values` in order to automatically recalculate totals with every change.

```js
$scope.$watch('values', function() {
  $scope.groupedNames = groupByName($scope.values);
});
```

#### [Demo in Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LL7nRkKriHpEqlLEJi7R?p=preview)

Answer (score -1):

You can build a TotalArray with the actual name (key) of your input as key and the count as value with it. Iterate over the input pairs and check if there is already a key called the key of this iteration if so: add the count to its value, otherwise create a new one in the TotalArray.

Some pseudo code that might help you:

```
inputArray = text.split('\n')
outputArray = []
for(i = 0, i< length, i++) {
    name = inputArray[i].split(',')[0]
    count = inputArray[i].split(',')[1]
    if (outputArray[name] exists) {
        outputArray[name] += count
    } else {
        outputArray[name] = count
    }
}
```

Now outputArray contains [[name1] => total_count1, [name2] => total_count2,... ]

I hope this helps you.