# how to render the options inside angular select box

Tags: angularjs

How do i render the values inside dropdown(selectbox options).
I need to show '**header**' and '**footer**' names inside selectbox.

```
$scope.sections = [
   {
      "header":{
         "background-color":"#fff",
         "color":"#fff"
      },
      "footer":{
         "background-color":"#fff",
         "color":"#fff"
      }
   }
];
```

I tried in the following way but not working,

```
<select name="section" class="form-control" ng-model ="section">
   <option ng:repeat="options[0] in sections">
        {{options[0]}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954286/angularjs-how-can-i-reference-the-property-name-within-an-ng-repeat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over keys instead of values.

```
<option ng-repeat="(option, val) in sections[0]">
    {{option}}
</option>
```

Or with ng-options

```
ng-options="option for (option, val) in sections[0]"
```

see the plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/FQEooL5wNh8Xl8GprT99?p=preview

Comment: Perfect!. Thanks and +1 :-).  How can we achieve the same using ng-options? is it possible ??